# How to change the names of all classes in particular div?

Tags: css, class

I need to replace dynamically created class names to avoid conflicts with the same names in CSS, so I need to add prefix or suffix to every class in one div.

In short - how can I change something like this:

```
<div id="example" class="super awesome class"></div>
```

Into e.g. this?:

```
<div id="example" class="super_text awesome_text class_text"></div>
```

Comment: But...if you change the class-names, how were you planning to style the elements with those classes? If you're using class-names to track state/interaction, in some way, then you might as well use the `data-*` attributes and *not* complicate your life.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be easiest in JavaScript:

```
var elems = document.getElementById('example');

elems.className = elems.classList.join('_text ')+'_text';
```

Make sure you don't forget the space at the end of the `join()` text, otherwise it will combine all of your class names into one.